Firebase Realtime Database REST API returns Unauthorized, even with token
I'm writting a Blazor Server app that connects to Firebase Realtime Database. I'm using the FirebaseDatabase SDK but need to perform a set of Atomic operations updating multiple Paths. Since the SDK do not have a method for that, I've decided to use REST API.
I'm already able to Authenticate using email/pass, which gives me access to currentUser.GetIdTokenAsync();
I'm able to read/write data on single Put/Patch operations.
But, when I try to update a path using the REST API, it fails saying: "Unauthorized".
In order to test this, I've written a simple code, below:
public async Task singleUpdate(string idPropriedade, string idLote, string novoNome)
{
    // Firebase database URL
    string firebaseUrl = DatabaseProjectSettings.projectURL;

    // Define the updates for each path
    string jsonContent = 
        "{" +
            "\"lotes\": {" +
                "\"" + idPropriedade + "\": {" +
                    "\"" + idLote + "\": {" +
                        "\"nomePropriedade\": \"" + novoNome + "\"" +
                    "}" +
                "}" +
            "}" +
        "}";


    var token = await _currUser.GetIdTokenAsync(true);


    // Create HttpClient instance
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // Configure the request
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Put,
            RequestUri = new Uri($"{firebaseUrl}.json"),
            Content = new StringContent(jsonContent, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");

        // Send the request and get the response
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        // Check if the request was successful
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Paths updated successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to update paths. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
        }
    }
}

If I remove the database rules, the write operation works fine. If I leave the database rules, I get the "Unauthorized" message.
I have already tested to use the token on the URL as follow, using both "auth" or "access_token": RequestUri = new Uri($"{firebaseUrl}.json?access_token={token}"), without success!
This is the response in VStudio:

Please send me your insights! Thanks!

As shown in the docs on authenticating with an ID token, you need to pass that token in an auth parameter in the URL.
The Authorization header and access_token parameter are only used to authenticate with an OAuth2 access token.

Thanks, Frank. But I've already tried both "auth" and "access_token". Result is still unauthorized. I'm adding the error screen to the question. If you have any other suggestions, please add them.

Is it clear from my answer why the passing an ID token in the access_token parameter or in the Authentication header doesn't work? Those were the two approaches that you had in your question originally, and my answer should explain why those didn't work. --- Rather than expanding the question to show that you also can't get the proper approach that I pointed out to work, see What should I do when someone answers my question? and post a new question with a minimal repro of the new approach.

Thanks, Frank. Yes, it is clear. As I've mentioned. I have tried passing the "auth" parameter as well, and it still does not work. I had no intention to expand the question, but to tell you that I have tried both ways, before posting the question.


If I remove the database rules, the write operation works fine. If I leave the database rules, I get the "Unauthorized" message.

The SDK runs under a service account that probably has full read/write access. When going thru the API, then make sure that your currentUser matches an allow update and/or allow create rule in your Firestore rules for the paths/documents you're trying to write to.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Thanks, Keith! Rules are pretty simple: "auth.uid != null", but no success.

The added screenshot was very helpful, it looks like your request URL looks wrong. You're missing a path after the firebaseUrl variable -- you only have a /.json after the API URL.
From the screenshot, your URL looks like:
https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/.json

It should have at least one path element, so if you're trying to put data under lotes:
https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/lotes.json

You may also want to change your jsonContent to remove the outer lotes
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database

Thanks, Keith. The way it is now, with only the .json, it saves on the root. It is working fine if I remove the security rules. The issue happens when the security rules are set.
